# child component is not rendering in main component in angular. its rendering separetly when I click on button

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have a main component named main-header having a menu with three buttons labeled as "Desktop", "Web" and "Mobile" .when I click a menu button it renders in a new screen but I want to render in my main component that is main-header.

**main-header.component.html**

```
<div class="main-header">
    <h1>{{appTitle}}</h1>
    <button type=""><a routerLink="/main-header/desktop">Desktop</a></button>
    <button type=""><a routerLink="/main-header/web">Web</a></button>
    <button type=""><a routerLink="/main-header/mobile">Mobile</a></button>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**desktop.component.html**

```
<p>
  desktop works!
</p>
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {MainHeaderComponent} from './containers/main-header/main-header.component';
import {DesktopComponent} from './containers/desktop/desktop.component';
import {WebComponent} from './containers/web/web.component';
import {MobileComponent} from './containers/mobile/mobile.component';


export const router: Routes =[
    {path: '', redirectTo:'main-header', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'main-header', children:[
        {path:'', component:MainHeaderComponent, pathMatch:'full'},
        {path: 'desktop', component:DesktopComponent},
        {path: 'web', component: WebComponent},
        {path: 'mobile', component: MobileComponent}
    ]}
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

Comment: You can use *ngIf and declare the subcomponent in the parent component. When click the button, then change a boolean to true to show the component

Comment: you would need to have a proper parent page, so add `component:MainHeaderComponent` to the second parent path instead of the first child

Comment: i like how the angularjs tag got removed from an angularjs project

Comment: Please **do not** add the angularJS tag for questions involving angular v2+. _Use for questions about AngularJS, the open-source JavaScript framework. Do NOT use this tag for Angular 2 or later versions; instead, use the "angular" tag._ @mast3rd3mon There's a good reason why...

Comment: it is an angularjs question, it uses divs

Comment: i use angular 2 with nativescript every day

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Then you should know that angular1 is very different from angular2. The `angularjs` tag is for angular1 questions as stated in its description. I'm not commenting anymore as this is now polluting the comments of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of route the component show it when you want to.

```
<div class="main-header">
    <h1>{{appTitle}}</h1>
    <button type=""><a href="javascript: void(0)"(click)="changeBoolean()">Desktop</a></button>
</div>
<child-compoent *ngIf="istrue()"></child-component>
```

The parent component would have somethig like:

```
export class ParentComponent {

  private showComponent = false;

  constructor() { }

  public changeBoolean() {
    this.showComponent = true;
  }

  public isTrue() {
    return this.showComponent;
  }
```

Comment: istrue() is a method which will be called on button click to make property true ?

Comment: When click the button changeBoolean is called. Then, a boolean is changed to true in the component and isTrue() returns the boolean changed before. Angular is evaluating everytime there is change